# SQL statement to return student's best grade

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows with student's exam results in:

[image: My Table]

I want a SQL statement that will return the student's best grade:

Student 1 - Maths A

Student 2 - Maths D

etc.....

I have tried MAX() on the date, DISTINCT, Grouping By... But I think I'm fumbling in the dark.

**EDIT:** I should say that MIN and MAX on the grade will not work as A* is a possible grade and alphabetically comes after A which is incorrect. Grades could be a variety of letters and numbers which have no logical ranking (e.g. L1 is better than EL1 but L3 is better than L1). Possibly a subtable with ranking is required?

Comment: I should say that MIN and MAX on the grade will not work as A* is a possible grade and alphabetically comes after A which is incorrect.

Comment: Could you update your question and include which grades you store, and what the order is from best to worst?

Comment: @tonyyeb please add that comment to the question, it's important information

Comment: If you cannot tell a specific list of Grades how do you expect sql server to know what is better and what is worst. I would suggest creating a Table specific to Grades and add an INT column there to specify the Order Best--> Worst for each possible Grade. and use that table to decide grades of each student.

Comment: you need to create a linked ranking table that shows you which grades are better than others and link to that

Comment: I think another table with the ranking is required and then a MAX should work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT StudentName
       ,MIN(Grade)  Best_Grade
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY StudentName
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer because with another table with the grade ranking linked this will work. Thanks.

Comment: @tonyyeb if you have multiple subjects this wont work. in that case change : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3de2a4/4/0

Comment: @Vland in that case OP will need to add Subjects in Select and group by and it will return best grade for each student in each subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Please try below query in SQL :


 create table #test_table(
        name varchar(20),
        subjects varchar(20),
        grade varchar,
        resultdate datetime
    )

    insert into #test_table
    select 'student1', 'math', 'A','2012-09-01' union all 
    select 'student1', 'math', 'B','2013-09-01' union all 
    select 'student2', 'math', 'D','2014-09-01' union all 
    select 'student1', 'math', 'A','2014-09-01'

    select * from(
    select row_number() over(partition by name,subjects order by grade,resultdate desc) as rn,* from #test_table ) tbl where rn=1

    drop table #test_table
```